# How to lag() the previous data of specific category only?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Sample date:

```
Date          Type    Revenue
2019/01/01    A       100 
2019/02/01    A       200
2019/03/01    A       200

2019/01/01    B       100
2019/02/01    B       50

2019/01/01    C       500
2019/02/01    C       600
```

I want to know how many percentage the revenue  increase or decrease comparing to the last month. Here is my sample code

```
select to_date(date, 'yyyy-mm') as date, type, sum(revenue) as revenue
       lag(revenue, 1) over (order by service_type, date) as last_month
       round(((revenue - last_month::float)/last_month)::float*100,2) as percentage_growth

from #a
group by 1,2
order by 2,1;
```

The result of my code

```
Date          Type    Revenue     Last_month    Percentage_growth
2019/01/01    A       100         None          None
2019/02/01    A       200         100           100%
2019/03/01    A       200         200           100%

2019/01/01    B       100         200           -100%  --Here is the matter
2019/02/01    B       50          100           -50%

2019/01/01    C       500         50            900%   --Here is the matter
2019/02/01    C       600         500           20%
```

As you already seen, in the new type, `lag()` function still fetch the previous revenue of different type.

How to deal with it many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to dealing with different types is including "partition by type" in the lag window function.  Here is your query rewritten with subqueries which I find more readable.

```
select date, type, revenue, last_month, 
    round((revenue - last_month)/last_month::numeric*100.0::numeric,2) as percentage_growth 
    from (
        select date, type, revenue, lag(revenue, 1) over (partition by type order by type, date) as last_month
        from (
            select to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm'::text) as date, type, sum(revenue) as revenue
            from #a
            group by 1,2
        ) dd
    ) d
order by 2,1;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be cofounding the use of aggregate functions with window functions.  Given that you want to return the original table, you should be using only window functions here.  Here is a working version of your query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(revenue, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Type, Date) AS last_month
    FROM a
)

SELECT *,
    100.0 * (revenue - COALESCE(last_month, revenue)) / COALESCE(last_month, revenue) AS pct_growth
FROM cte;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value per type, you want `partition by` in the `lag()`.  The rest of the query seems off, so I would suggest:

```
select to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm') as date,
       type, revenue as revenue, last_month
       round((revenue - last_month::float) / last_month)::float*100, 2) as percentage_growth
from (select a.*,
             lag(revenue, 1) over (partition by service_type order by date) as last_month
      from #a
     ) a
order by 2, 1;
```